# How do I group and/or force the location of nodes in a DiagrammeR graph in R?

Tags: r, graph, flowchart, diagrammer

I'm using the `DiagrammeR` R package to try to create a flowchart that looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XwUy.png). I've run into a couple hurdles. The first is that I can't figure out how to 'group' the nodes and draw a box around them, and the less important hurdle is that I don't know how to have the nodes in a specific order (at least on the top row). The current result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tCsa.png).

My code is here:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
library(tidyverse)

test <- create_graph() %>% 
  add_nodes_from_table("data/tbm_nodes.csv", label_col = label) %>% 
  add_edges_from_table("data/tbm_edges.csv", from_col = from, to_col = to, from_to_map = id_external) %>% 
  set_node_attrs(shape, "box") %>% 
  set_node_attrs(fixedsize, "false")
  
render_graph(test, layout = "tree")
```

The `nodes` dataset has an `income` column with 'high' or 'low', as well as `id` and `label` columns, and the `edges` dataset has just the `from` and `to` information.

I've looked through the documentation pretty thoroughly for both the R package and graphviz (which `DiagrammeR` uses (I'm pretty sure? Unless I'm very mistaken)), but nothing has seemed to help. I've tried setting a `group` for each node based on `income`, but that didn't work. Neither did setting absolute position values with `set_node_position()`. The 'tree' layout is perfect except for the grouping and first row node order, but maybe I need to set each node position individually and not use 'tree'? This would be a non-ideal approach of course.

I'm not sure what else to try at this point, I'm wondering if what I want to do is even possible with `DiagrammeR`?

Comment: In Graphviz terms, create 2 clusters (see https://graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf), one high-income and one low-income.  Assign nodes accordingly